# Python nested lambda expression still confused and couldn't understandable. please explain the following example

Tags: python, lambda

```
>>> test = lambda f: f(lambda x: x + 1)(0)
>>> z = lambda f: lambda x: x
>>> test(z)
0

>>> succ = lambda n: lambda f: lambda x: f(n(f)(x))
>>> _1 = succ(z)
>>> test(_1)
1

>>> _2 = succ(_1)
>>> test(_2)
2

>>> plus = lambda m: lambda n: lambda f: lambda x: m(f)(n(f)(x))
>>> _3 = plus(_1)(_2)
>>> test(_3)
3

>>> mult = lambda m: lambda n: lambda f: lambda x: m(n(f))(x)
>>> _6 = mult(_2)(_3)
>>> test(_6)
6

>>> _5 = plus(_2)(_3)
>>> _25 = mult(_5)(_5)
>>> _4 = plus(_2)(_2)
>>> _100 = mult(_25)(_4)
>>> test(_100)
100
```

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to do something completely horrible?

Comment: which line don't you understand?

Comment: test = lambda f: f(lambda x: x + 1)(0)

z = lambda f: lambda x: x

test(z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First avoid same name hidden (local) variables to avoid extra confusion (as if you need anymore! :)

```
>>> test = lambda f: f(lambda x: x + 1)(0)
>>> z = lambda g: lambda y: y
>>> test(z)
0
```

Go step by step replacing the variables by their value:

```
test(z) = z(lambda x: x + 1)(0)
```

Now `z` is a function that return the identity function `lambda y: y` no matter what argument is passed (`g` does not appear in the expression defining the `lambda`).

```
test(z) = (lambda y: y)(0) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I applied your method   to solve the second part of the above problem. But i couldn't replace succ(z) in aproper way. That is  complicated than first part. Will you explain?

Comment: Just apply the the same procedure and show me what you get.

Comment: succ(z)=lambda n: lambda y:y(lambda x:f(n(f)(x))(0)                                   Is it correct? How to solve after this?

Comment: looks like you don't understand what a lambda is, maybe you should read about it...